# Expectation of absolute value of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, expectation, brownian-motion

I'm working on this problem that I can't seem to figure out. The problem involves a 1-dimensional Brownian motion, $B_t$, where the subscript denotes the time, and it asks me to show that the expectation
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|B_t-B_s|^4]=3|t-s|^2
\end{align}
where $s<t$.
I'm new to the subject of Brownian motion, so I'm not quite sure how to deal with this. I know that $B_t-B_s$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean zero and variance $t-s$. My intuition was therefore to compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|B_t-B_s|^4] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x|^4 ~f(x)~dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^4~f(x)~dx
\end{align}
where $x$ denotes the value of the random variable $B_t-B_s$, and $f(x)$ denotes its distribution, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(t-s)}}$. However, that's just the 4th moment of a normal distribution, which is $3(t-s)^4$, so I know that something is wrong with my intuition. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong, or give a hint to what a better (or correct) approach would be?

Comment: If $X\sim N(0, t-s)$, where $t-s$ is the *variance*, and the fourth moment is $3\sigma^4$, then $E(X^4)=3\sigma^4=3\sqrt{t-s}^4=3(t-s)^2$, right? Sounds like your intuition is right, but mixing up standard deviation and variance.

Comment: @hejseb That's totally true! Thanks for pointing that out!